# Avoiding PhpStorm vue tag string line breaks in function arguments

Tags: javascript, vue.js, phpstorm

How to tell PhpStorm not to make line breaks between Vue double curly braces {{ }} and in the function arguments?

Expected is to keep it like that
[image]

However after ALT + SHIFT + F it looks like that

[image]

Comment: Did you try with `backward` slash at the end of the first line ?

Comment: This string is translation key, it must be exactly as it is and cannot be formatted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer. Unchecking HTML Code Style setting "Wrap text" does the trick.

[image]